# Bootstrap: adding button group to navbar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is it easy enough to add a `btn-group` to `navbar` in `bootstrap`? `btn` is fine, but not so much so when `btn-group/div`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enclose the button group in a form and use the `form-inline` class.

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gptZg/)

Answer (score 14):

In Bootstrap3, you can add a `navbar-btn` class to your buttons to have them vertical-align, even in a `btn-group`.

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-buttons